# Latency with www prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-hosting

Recently bought a new domain (cloud hosting account).Discovered that my site adds extra delay when invoked with "WWW" prefix in the browser.

However, the site does appear finally but its slower compare to invoking without "WWW"

why is this slow ? and can i improve this with any configuration ?
what is the best practice.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @ksno sorry added.

Answer (score 0):

1]Once anyone register domain, domain name will be in naked form. Purpose is to link it to specific IP.Suppose example.com is domain name which is naked domain name linked to specific IP.Once domain is created, zone will be created too for it.

2]www.example.com shows sub domain of domain example.com and it has zone records automatically set which is of main domain example.com.So whenever someone browse www.example.com,it tries to identify zone records of example.com and then displays website.Hence there could be slight delay(mili seconds) while one would browse www.example.com compare to example.com

3]One should bind domain with www and without www